# iOS Swift 3 - UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uidatepicker

I have a `UIDatePicker` that shows the day, month and the year. But I don't know how to get those parameters.

So What is the best way to get the day, month and year from `UIDatePicker` using Swift 3?

Comment: your qurestion is not clear

Comment: can you show ur tried code

Comment: You want to get selected date from picker ?

Comment: What kind of date picker you want , I mean to say that whether you want to embed date picker into your textfield or you just want to use as popover on the screen

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In Swift 3 you can use `DateComponents` for that like this way.

First add action on `datepicker` for `.valueChanged` events.

```
datepicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dateChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

Then get selected day, month and year using `DateComponents` in the action.

```
func dateChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: sender.date)
    if let day = components.day, let month = components.month, let year = components.year {
        print("\(day) \(month) \(year)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't notice and made the mistake of registering my action with the `touchUpInside` event. Yet I should do it for `.valueChanged`

Answer (score 68):

**UIDatePicker in Swift 3  and Swift 4 example.**

***In Swift 3 You can use***

1. Create Simple Project of Single View Application in swift 3
2. Drag a text field & connect to viewController
3. Date picker look like  image

[image]

1. **ViewController code is bellow.**.

   ```
     class ViewController: UIViewController {
        //Text Field Connection
      @IBOutlet weak var txtDatePicker: UITextField!
      //Uidate picker
      let datePicker = UIDatePicker()

       override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
      //show date picker
        showDatePicker()
     }


      func showDatePicker(){
      //Formate Date
       datePicker.datePickerMode = .date

       //ToolBar
      let toolbar = UIToolbar();
      toolbar.sizeToFit()

      //done button & cancel button
       let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.bordered, target: self, action: "donedatePicker")
       let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
      let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.bordered, target: self, action: "cancelDatePicker")
      toolbar.setItems([doneButton,spaceButton,cancelButton], animated: false)

   // add toolbar to textField
   txtDatePicker.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    // add datepicker to textField
   txtDatePicker.inputView = datePicker

      }

    func donedatePicker(){
     //For date formate
      let formatter = DateFormatter()
      formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
      txtDatePicker.text = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
      //dismiss date picker dialog
      self.view.endEditing(true)
       }

         func cancelDatePicker(){
          //cancel button dismiss datepicker dialog
           self.view.endEditing(true)
         }
      }
   ```
2. Full Source project is given to github. github Link:https://github.com/enamul95/DatePicker1

   **In Swift 4 or 5 you can use bellow code**

   ```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

      @IBOutlet weak var txtDatePicker: UITextField!
     let datePicker = UIDatePicker()

     override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
        showDatePicker()
     }


     func showDatePicker(){
       //Formate Date
       datePicker.datePickerMode = .date

      //ToolBar
      let toolbar = UIToolbar();
      toolbar.sizeToFit()
      let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(donedatePicker));
      let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
     let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelDatePicker));

    toolbar.setItems([doneButton,spaceButton,cancelButton], animated: false)

     txtDatePicker.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
     txtDatePicker.inputView = datePicker

    }

     @objc func donedatePicker(){

      let formatter = DateFormatter()
      formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
      txtDatePicker.text = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
      self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    @objc func cancelDatePicker(){
       self.view.endEditing(true)
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: You can also use localized done and cancel bar buttons as follows (Swift 4, don't know in 3):      let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.done, target: self, action: #selector(donedatePicker))      let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.cancel, target: self, action: #selector(cancelDatePicker))

Answer (score 17):

Suppose if you want to show datePicker on tapping textfield and when user select some date from it then it will automatically populate on your textfield .

```
 @IBOutlet weak var dateTextField: UITextField!
let datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date
        dateTextField.inputView = datePickerView
        datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.datePickerValueChanged), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)

// Make a dateFormatter in which format you would like to display the selected date in the textfield.
func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

        dateFormatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.medium

        dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.none

        dateTextField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)

    }
```

Here Sender.date which is the instance of UIDatePicker pick up the date from the datepicker and populate on your textfield.

Comment: I didn't know about inputView... So much time won. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Create `IBOutlet` of `UIDatePicker` and connect it properly then use below code to get day, month, year ect.

```
var comp = NSDateComponents()
@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: Selector("datePickerChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
}

func datePickerChanged(datePicker:UIDatePicker){
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
    let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    comp = cal.components([.Era, .Day, .Month, .Year, .Hour, .Minute] , fromDate: datePicker.date)

    // getting day, month, year ect
    print ("Era:\(comp.era) Date:\(comp.day) Month:\(comp.month) Month:\(comp.year) Hours: \(comp.hour) Minuts:\(comp.minute)")
}
```

Comment: OP has asked in Swift 3, So batter to use `DateComponents` instead of `NSDateComponents` and `Calendar` instead of `NSCalendar`.

Comment: @NiravD it's a version diff, anyway appreciating your contribution here +one for you also :)

Comment: @vaibhav not calling `super` from `viewDidLoad` is a serious error.

Comment: @dirtydanee that was formatting issue just rectified, `super` was already there.

Answer (score 5):

Swift 5 users can try this it works for me

```
import UIKit

class FreeCallsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var dateTextField: UITextField!

let datepicker = UIDatePicker()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func calenderButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.createDatePicker()
}

func createDatePicker() {
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    
    let donebtn = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donepressed))
    
    toolbar.setItems([donebtn], animated: true)
    
    dateTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    
    dateTextField.inputView = datepicker
    
    datepicker.datePickerMode = .date
}
@objc func donepressed() {
    let dateformator = DateFormatter()
    
    dateformator.dateStyle = .medium
    dateformator.timeStyle = .none
    
    
    
    dateTextField.text = dateformator.string(from: datepicker.date)
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

```
var picker = UIDatePicker()
picker = UIDatePicker()
textField.inputView = picker
picker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleDatePicker), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
picker.datePickerMode = .date

func handleDatePicker() {
    var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
    textfield.text = dateFormatter.string(from: picker.date)
    textfield.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> **Swift 5.0+**

> I hope it will work for you, Enjoy!

```
import UIKit

protocol SKUIDatePickerDelegate:class {
    func getDate(_ sKUIDatePicker:SKUIDatePicker, date:String)
    func cancel(_ sKUIDatePicker:SKUIDatePicker)
}

class SKUIDatePicker:UIView {
    
    private let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    private var dateFormate = "yyyy/mm/dd"
    weak var delegate:SKUIDatePickerDelegate?
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        // self.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func showDatePicker(txtDatePicker:UITextField){
        //Formate Date
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        
        //ToolBar
        let toolbar = UIToolbar();
        toolbar.sizeToFit()
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action:       #selector(donedatePicker));
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem:       UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action:       #selector(cancelDatePicker));
        
        toolbar.setItems([doneButton,spaceButton,cancelButton], animated:       false)
        
        txtDatePicker.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
        txtDatePicker.inputView = datePicker
        
    }
    
    @objc func donedatePicker(){
        
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = dateFormate
        let result = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        self.delegate?.getDate(self, date: result)
        
    }
    
    @objc func cancelDatePicker(){
        self.delegate?.cancel(self)
    }
    
}
```

> **Usage**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,SKUIDatePickerDelegate {
    //Text Field Connection
    @IBOutlet weak var txtDatePicker: UITextField!
    
    private var skUIdatePicker:SKUIdatePicker?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        skUIdatePicker = SKUIdatePicker()
        skUIdatePicker.delegate = self
        skUIdatePicker.showDatePicker(txtDatePicker:txtDatePicker)
    }
    
    func getDate(_ sKUIDatePicker:SKUIDatePicker, date:String) {
        print(date)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
    func cancel(_ sKUIDatePicker:SKUIDatePicker){
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem can be solved in numerous way. If you are looking for a solution only using code:

```
    class Foo: UIViewController {
        // Lets create your picker - Can be IBOutlet too
        lazy var datePicker: UIDatePicker = {
            let picker = UIDatePicker()
            picker.datePickerMode = .date
            return picker
        }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Observe the value changes in datePickerValueChanged function for example
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)
    }

    func datePickerValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        // Function will be called every time picker changes it's value
        // You can access to it the following way
        print(sender.date)
    }
  }
```

The other way if you have your `UIDatePicker` in Interface Builder. You pretty much need to the same thing, like above, but i a slightly different way. Click on your `UIDatePicker` in Interface Builder:

[image]

You see the `Value Changed` option at the buttom. Now you grab and drag an `IBAction` to your viewController, and set up your connection like this:

[image]

This way you achive the same as the first example, because you end up with pretty much the same function:

```
@IBAction func datePickerValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    print(sender.date)
}
```